# Firebase push is deleting previously pushed data

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a JavaFX application that uses the Firebase server SDK to store data. The problem is the push() method. When calling push() anytime after the first time the application is loaded, it deletes the previously pushed data when it pushes the new data. They have different push ids so I see no reason why this should be happening.

The relevant line is:

```
firebaseDataRef.push().setValue(myData)
```

Comment: That seems very unlikely. Can you show a minimal program that I can run that reproduces the problem?